# Centering in columns with a malleable number of columns

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to list a series of same sized elements. I want these elements to display with even spacing on the right and left (vertically centered?), and evenly spaced between each other. The biggest problem is that the list needs to be able to adjust to screen size changes and number of element changes. As such the width and elements per line need to update as necessary. The bottom row should also ideally align with those above it.

This is the closest that I have been able to get so far.

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
... repeated as any times as there are blocks.
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  text-align: justify;
  margin:0;
  width: auto; 
}

.outer {
  background:blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  background:red;
  width: 90px; 
  height: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdL9ent2/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for flexbox.  One of these work for you?  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEpbjv

HTML

```
  <ul class="flex-container space-between">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container space-around">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container space-evenly">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-start { 
  justify-content: flex-start; 
}

.flex-end { 
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}  
.flex-end li {
  background: gold;
}

.center { 
  justify-content: center; 
}  
.center li {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.space-between { 
  justify-content: space-between; 
}  
.space-between li {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.space-around { 
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
.space-around li {
  background: hotpink; 
}

.space-evenly { 
  justify-content: space-evenly; 
}
.space-evenly li {
  background: #bada55; 
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: With "flex-wrap: wrap" added to ".flex-container", it works exactly as I want it to. Thank you very much.